# ImportError: No module named pywinauto

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, pywinauto

I am using python 2.7 on a windows 10 machine and have built an application I need to package into an exe. I have tried with py2exe and am getting an error. Unfortunately I am on a work laptop and they only allow py2exe and I have tried every option on stack overflow. Below I have my setup.py file. I have also tried deleting the egg and that is not working either.

```
File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    "includes": ["pywinauto"]
  File "C:\Users\dcarlo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\dcarlo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\dcarlo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\dcarlo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\dcarlo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "C:\Users\dcarlo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1297, in find_needed_modules
    mf.import_hook(mod)
  File "C:\Users\dcarlo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Users\dcarlo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Users\dcarlo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named pywinauto
```

---

```
from distutils.core import setup
import pywinauto
import py2exe

setup(console=['plugwalk.py'],
      options=
      {
          "py2exe":
              {
                  "includes": ["pywinauto"]
              }
      }
```

Comment: Have u tried this [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/mailman/py2exe-users/thread/l1u22c$ark$1@ger.gmane.org/) ? It talks about including pywinauto modules in pywinauto sub-folder like this `"includes": ["pywinauto.tests.allcontrols"]` . May be such way of inclusion can work.

Comment: I did try a few options like that and just tried this one. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a library being stored in a sub folder in site packages. Just move the folder to the main directory and it will solve the problem.